# Fighting Animation In Blender

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, blender

I am working on 3D gaming fighting project. In which I have to make a game in which two player fight..I am using Unity3D and Blender and after four month experience i am quite experience with these two..Now i am going to make some real stuff.Now i have a character and i want to make his basic fight moves which should be realistic just like other game have like Taken 3 etc..So would you plz suggest me some blender tutorial and some other stuff which guide me to make such types of animation just like make a punch animation, walk animation, hit a leg animation, in blender.SO is there any help...

Comment: -1 because 1.) Google is your friend 2.) you never accepted an answer

Comment: Actually i have search a lot on google for this type of thing but i could't get the right one...I have found many good tutorial on this platform which i am not be able to find directly on google.So thats why i have posted here so that i can find direct link...I think this is not a bad way to do this..We must use shortcut rather to explore each and every thing...Kay and Joetjah

Comment: i can make simple animation ..I can make more then one animation in one fbx file in blender i can make all these animation but they are not accurate i mean they don't look so much realistic so thats why i want a tutorial through which i can learn that how can we do some real fighting punch and kick due to these reason i have posted here.

Comment: @Joetjah OK agree with you, kind of overreaction because it's sometimes annoying to see 0 acccept rates. My 'Google' was similar to your 'What have you tried already' and was actually the main reason for downvoting. Well after clarifying that the question is related to the artist point of view I revoked the downvote :)

Comment: People come here to learn, the reputation is to motivate people to give that answer or elaborate on it for more upvotes. I've always felt like I wanted someone else to learn from it or help them, rather then giving myself rep points. Else I wouldn't be stuck in the Unity3d-tag :) @OP, that put's your question in a whole other perspective. That's why you should always try to explain as much as possible

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve those things you mentioned I think you should learn about ***Character Rigging, Walk-cycles, Character Animations...etc***.

Now, For the **Character Rigging** part checkout these links:

http://cgcookie.com/blender/2011/12/12/blender-introduction-to-character-rigging/

http://www.blenderguru.com/videos/introduction-to-rigging/

You can also google for more info on this topic

Now, you can google the other remaining topics like walk-cycles, character animation..etc. Once you master all those techniques, you will be able to create realistic character movements. And don't forget to dig through the above links, these sites contain some very good tutorials. Plus there are numerous youtube video tutorials on this topic.

Good Luck